# Wrong path in source map

Tags: reactjs, npm

Running npm start on my react project gives me a lot of warnings like this:

> Failed to parse source map from myapp\node_modules\sanitize-html\node_modules\htmlparser2\lib\https:\raw.githubusercontent.com\fb55\htmlparser2\c123610e003a1eaebc61febed01cabb6e41eb658\src\Tokenizer.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

There is a clear issue with the path containing that **https:** as it's not valid and it seems to have concatenated a remote URL and my local path. This happens only on one package *sanitize-html*.

Am I doing something wrong?

I am running this on windows and the app seems to work fine. I am not looking for a fix like disabling source map generation, but just trying to understand why this happens.